# ¿Porqué se cierra la app al instante en Android?

Tags: java, python, android, google-maps

Estoy creando una app de android con Python, y compilando con Buildozer, quiero usar los servicios de google maps para obtener mi ubicación, llevo el siguiente código, mi objetivo es crear una app que obtenga tu ubicación y te guíe dentro de una universidad, está pensada para personas discapacitadas, pero no logro hacer que la app funcione en un dispositivo android:

```
import pygame
import random
import os
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime

# Configurar la ventana Pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
pygame_head = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath('.') + '/laga.png').convert_alpha()
current_color = (255, 0, 0)
counter = 0
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)  # Fuente para el contador
button_rect = pygame.Rect(150, 300, 100, 50)  # Rectángulo del botón
button_color = (0, 255, 0)  # Color del botón
button_text = font.render("Presionar", True, (0, 0, 0))  # Texto del botón

# Configurar la API de Google Geolocalización
api_key = 'Mi key'
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=api_key)

def draw_counter():
    counter_text = font.render(f"Contador: {counter}", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(counter_text, (10, 350))

def obtener_coordenadas():
    try:
        location = gmaps.geolocate()
        latitud = location['location']['lat']
        longitud = location['location']['lng']
        return latitud, longitud
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al obtener la ubicación: {str(e)}")
        return None

# Texto para mostrar las coordenadas
coordenadas_text = font.render("", True, (0, 0, 0))

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                current_color = (0, 255, 0)
                counter += 1
                # Obtener las coordenadas y mostrarlas en pantalla
                coordenadas = obtener_coordenadas()
                if coordenadas:
                    coordenadas_text = font.render(f"Latitud: {coordenadas[0]}, Longitud: {coordenadas[1]}", True, (0, 0, 0))

    screen.fill(current_color)
    screen.blit(pygame_head, (0, 0))
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, button_color, button_rect)
    text_rect = button_text.get_rect(center=button_rect.center)
    screen.blit(button_text, text_rect)
    
    draw_counter()
    
    # Mostrar las coordenadas en pantalla
    screen.blit(coordenadas_text, (10, 10))
    
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Ahora, funcionaba bien antes de agregar lo de google maps, sí se instala la app en el dispositivo, VS Code la ejecuta bien, pero al momento de dar clic en la app, se cierra al instante, este es el SPEC de buildozer que uso, no sé si esté correcto los permisos y los requerimientos:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = juego

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,pygame,jnius,sdl2,sdl2_image,sdl2_mixer,sdl2_ttf,png,jpeg,googlemaps

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

Comment: "se cierra al instante" -> Normalmente estas cosas generan algún tipo de log... sin él es imposible saber qué está pasando. Si tú, que tienes acceso al dispositivo y al código,no eres capaz de saber qué está pasando, cómo vamos a saberlo nosotros sin poder ejecutarlo??? Aquí la gente no usa bolas de cristal para saber qué pasa en el código de otros, usamos los mensajes de error (o ejecutamos el código, pero en casos como este la única opción viable es ver los logs).

Comment: El problema se debe a infinidad de causas, en este caso debes revisar el error que se despliega en el LogCat, agregalo a tu pregunta.